# MyBatis-like collection mapping using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, mybatis

Suppose I have 2 entities with 1-M relation - Accounts(1) and Addresses (M). Using MyBatis select, I can use a collection in the resultMap to map multiple records(or objects) of Addresses to 1 record(or object) of Accounts where Accounts.Id = Addresses.AccountId and thus return 1 single Accounts object with its Addresses collection populated with the matched records.

E.g. table Accounts has 1 record and Addresses has 2 records, and I write a query

```
select * from Accounts a join Addresses ad on a.Id = ad.AccountId
```

MyBatis will return 1 Accounts object with 2 Addresses added to its collection. i.e. Addresses(children) mapped to Accounts(parent). Of course, MyBatis gets 2 records for the JOIN too, but the collection mapping feature takes off that boring part from us where you map the Accounts with its Addresses manually.

Does hibernate have such a feature where I can tell it to give me the objects mapped by the parent-child relationship?

Comment: I do it all the time in MyBatis, but I haven't seen it in Hibernate or JPA. I'm curious how this can be done. +1